# Renaming of Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using sp_rename to switch table name , below is my query

```
exec sp_rename 'dbo.People_Daily' , 'TEMP'
exec sp_rename 'dbo.People_Future', 'People_Daily'
exec sp_rename 'TEMP',   'dbo.People_Future'
```

My questions is, what if I execute the same query in parallel with different table name,since im using TEMP word in both query, is there a possiblity that the TEMP in People will be used by Address?, what should I do to avoid this, is there any auto generated word to replace TEMP?

```
exec sp_rename 'dbo.Address_Daily' , 'TEMP'
exec sp_rename 'dbo.Addresse_Future', 'Address_Daily'
exec sp_rename 'TEMP',   'dbo.Address_Future'
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Well, why do you use `TEMP` then? Why not use a different name for each table, eg. `dbo.x_Address_Daily` or something like that? Also, if you're using `sp_rename` in your business logic, rather than in deployment DDLs, you're probably doing something very wrong :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `TEMP` can collide if your batches run in parallel. But you can use `TEMP` as an suffix to existing table name:

```
exec sp_rename 'dbo.People_Daily' , 'dbo.People_Daily_TEMP'
exec sp_rename 'dbo.People_Future', 'People_Daily'
exec sp_rename 'dbo.People_Daily_TEMP',   'dbo.People_Future'
```

and

```
exec sp_rename 'dbo.Address_Daily' , 'dbo.Address_Daily_TEMP'
exec sp_rename 'dbo.Addresse_Future', 'Address_Daily'
exec sp_rename 'dbo.Address_Daily_TEMP',   'dbo.Address_Future'
```

Then your batches won't collide.

Comment: I'm using variable for each table, this query will  be executed in a shell package so its possible that different configuration used this simultaneously, so i think this is good, i just use @User::strTablename + "_TEMP"